# Google Chrome redirects me to google.com.tr

Tags: google-chrome, windows-server-2008, redirection

I have a new Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have IIS 7.0 running with a couple of web sites.

I installed Google Chrome on the machine and it worked great, yesterday.

Today, I went to Chrome to look some stuff up and whenever I navigate to Google.com it ALWAYS redirects me to google.com.tr (Google Turkey).  I can get to other sites w/o issue.  Just not Google.com

Clearing browser settings/history, etc... fixes the issue - temporarily.  Navigating away and back the issue returns.

Is this a virus, or a bug in Chrome?

**EDIT**

This server is an Amazon EC2 Cloud system I believe running in their Oregon (US-West) datacenter.

I am not located in Turkey but central USA.

I have confirmed that ICANN has my server's ip address in seattle washington.  On my Amazon EC2 dashboard, the server location is Oregon (US-West).

I am currently running a full av scan - the quick scan found nothing unusual.

Curiously, while i can get to other web sites, ads that are served are served in what I think is Turkish!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google will send you to the domain depending on your IP location. It is most likely that your IP address is being picked up as being outside of your actual location.

Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet? This could be routing your traffic to an IP that is outside your actual location.

It is possible that you have a malicious program that is re-routing your info but it is most likely a miss-identification. I would do a WHOIS your IP and see where it is registered.

See this page for more information from Google: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en

Comment: I should have mentioned this is and Amazon EC2 Cloud system.

Comment: That could very well be where the IP problem is coming from. You can use the link that I provided to tell Google where you are. Just follow the directions at that site to correct the problem.

Comment: Thank you - following the link you provided has appeared to fix the problem - time will tell though.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

- Check your hosts file and proxy settings.
- Be sure that they're default (however you have them normally).

In addition to that:

- Be sure that wherever you are doesn't have some
  sort of peculiar DNS settings.

If they are (default), and they don't
   (the network you're on has standard DNS settings, nothing has changed
   etc.) and you do **not** live in turkey, then it is possibly malware.

*What "version" of google you're directed to is based on the country of your IPs origin.*

Answer (score 2):

I would start by checking my ip address and where ICANN thinks it is located. There are a lot of sites that offer this service, one of those is: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Then:

- is it just chrome or firefox, opera, internet explorer as well?

  - if it is just chrome i'd check the default language settings chrome://settings/languages and look for turkish if any.
- if it still persists then use google search encrypted from https://encrypted.google.com/ it is more secure anyway and it wont redirect you because its on its security policy.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I had the same problem when I was running the ZenMate extension on Chrome, I removed it and it went back to normal. As said previously, check your proxy settings.